# How to use the current thread to process a work queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, queue

What data structures do I use to implement the following logic?

1. read() is an asynchronous method that queues some workload
2. Only one workload may run at a time.
3. The first thread to queue a workload becomes the worker thread. It processes all work on the queue before returning. The next thread to invoke read() becomes the new worker thread, and so on...
4. If other threads invoke read() while a worker thread is processing the queue, they simply add to the end of the queue and return immediately.

I know how to implement this using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue and AtomicBoolean but I get the feeling there is a better way.

**CLARIFICATION**: A workload consists of invoking another asynchronous method called read2(). read2() is asynchronous but is not thread-safe. When I say a worker thread "processes the workload" it simply fires the first read operation and returns right away. When read2() completes, it invokes the next operation on the queue and so on. The entire API is asynchronous. As such, I'd like to avoid a dedicated consumer thread (there's no real need for it and it's bad for scalability).

Comment: So essentially you want the first thread in to act as the worker until the queue is exhausted?

Comment: Why so complicated? You don't want a processing thread busy-waiting?  I think you should stick to the normal way.

Comment: @Mark, yes. @toto, the entire API is asynchronous. There is no need for a dedicated worker thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "asynchronous method"?

Comment: I disagree with your statements that: 1) there is no need for a consumer thread (it's the way it's usually done) and that 2) it's bad for scalability (there's only one consumer thread, how does that scale badly?).

Comment: I don't like your first plan.  A 'thread A' firing any run(), run(2) async. callback can try to set the AtomicBoolean and fail because a 'thread B' is processing workloads already.  B could finish the queue and clear the AtomicBoolean before A gets to push its workload.  There is then nothing to process the workload from A.

Comment: @toto: an asynchronous method returns immediately and continues running in the background. Using a consumer thread is bad for scalability because it's not clear how you would 1000 different Socket objects, with users invoking read() on each one. Do you have 1000 consumer objects? one? ten? There is no clear-cut answer. The consumer thread model makes sense when the producer invokes a synchronous method that blocks for a long time before returning and you don't want users to wait. In our case, read2() is already asynchronous so using a consumer thread doesn't buy us anything.

Comment: @Martin: Excellent catch. I will reply to your answer below.

Comment: @Gili if you do have 1000 sockets, won't you have 1000 read() executing at the same time from the method you are proposing?  Isn't that a problem? Wouldn't you be better off not processing each read() request immediately? Or making read() non-asynchronous so that you can control how many you have running at one time?

Comment: @toto, you'd have 1000 read() running at the same time, but against different sockets so there is no thread-safety problem. And no, I don't want/need to control how many concurrent operations I have running at once, the OS or HD will queue read operations as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the uncertainty of detecting the exact state of a thread processing queue items or no, I suggest that every thread, no matter whether a user thread or some kernel thread firing an async callback,  that arrives at this system enqueues its workload and then attempts to process all items in the queue.  If some workloads request the issue of a non-threadsafe call, protect this call only with a CS/spinner - you say that these non-threadsafe calls are brief anyway, so a CS/spin lock would cost you very little.

Dump the AtomicBoolean.  While finding it clear does mean that no thread is processing the workloads in the queue, finding it set does not mean that a thread is processing items in the queue: there is third state - 'finished with items in the queue but not quite got around to clearing the boolean yet'.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Excellent catch on the race condition. I believe this is what you mean:  Thread1: setRunning(true); Process entire queue; Thread2: Add a task to the Queue; isRunning() returns true, so we exit;  Thread1: setRunning(false);  Ooops, there is a task on the queue but no one is running.

Comment: Martin, what is a CS/spinner?

Comment: Sorry - mainly Windoze developer talking :) CS: 'Critical Section' - 2-stage lock that spins in user-space for a while in the hope of obtaining the lock quickly, then falls back to a kernel lock. On U***, You could just spinlock - loop around an AtomicBoolean until you can set it, make the non-threadsafe call, clear the AtomicBoolean - that should work.  There may be issues with single-core hardware - spinlocks perform poorly on such systems, in fact, in the case of threads with differing priorities, they can livelock.  You may wish to implement a (lock/condVar?), fallback to cover this.

Comment: I will accept your answer if no one suggests a better solution in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design might be braking some important rule in software engineering whose name escapes me at the moment. Ideally, you should have one class be responsible for one thing so asking classes to change what they are responsible for depending on an external state is going to cause you some trouble.

I would recommend that you take the [Producer/Consumer Patter](http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-8-SECT-3.html) into consideration. Your Producer thread(s) will add work onto the queue and a Consumer thread would process the work. This ensures that your producer threads don't have to concern themselves with when they are responsible for taking work from the queue and when they are responsible for putting work on the queue, all they care about is putting work on the queue. Your Consumer thread will be dedicated to taking work from the queue and executing it and that's all it would do!

**Update base on your comment:** the producer doesn't have to be dedicated, all you do is have your read callback enqueue the work item (I assume it's something like a callback, but correct me if I'm wrong). Here it is again:

```
private static BlockingQueue q;
// Asynchronous callback
public void read()
{
    q.enqueue(new WorkItem());
}
```

The consumer may have to be dedicated, but conceptually there is very little difference between dedicating a consumer and having multiple producers take an exclusive role as a consumer:

```
public class Consumer imlpements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue _queue;
    public Consumer(BlockingQueue q){
        _queue = q;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            // block on dequeue until there is work in the queue (i.e. never exits the loop)
            WorkItem w = _queue.dequeue();
            w.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can run <strike>both</strike> the Consumer <strike>and the Producer(s)</strike> in a thread pool (ExecutorService) and it will do exactly what you want it to do. Note that I have not included all the bells and whistles of thread safety, such as catching the interrupt exceptions and terminating gracefully, but that's something that you can (and should) add.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but a main point of the read() method is that it's asynchronous. The entire point is to avoid running dedicated threads as you suggest. When I speak of the worker thread "processing the queue" it's worth noting that it invokes methods which are asynchronous as well so it returns *very* fast.

Comment: Is it a problem to have a dedicated consumer thread? By asking the "producers" to do the consumer's work you're essentially dedicating a single consumer. You don't have to dedicate the producer threads, but why is a dedicated consumer an issue?

Comment: The producer is not a dedicated thread because it invokes asynchronous methods itself. It invokes the first read on the queue and returns very quickly. Sorry, I should have clarified that in the original question.

Comment: @Gili, I get the point about the Producer: it doesn't have to be on a dedicated thread, it's fine if you just have it enqueue the work into the queue... no problem there. However, in my last comment I was asking about the **Consumer**, can the **Consumer** be on a dedicated thread?

Comment: your suggestion makes perfect sense is read2() was synchronous and you couldn't block read() while it went about it's business. Seeing how read2() is asynchronous I don't think using a dedicated consumer buys you much. It kills scalability for no good reason (thread per socket model).

Comment: @Gili so when/how will you have more than one workload in the queue?  If read2() invokes the next operation in the queue and the operation calls read2() again, then how does the operation get on the queue to begin with?

Comment: Multiple threads invoke read(), adding to the queue each time. The first thread to invoke read() with an empty queue fires read2(). When read2() completes it will pop the next operation off the queue and invoke read2() again (with different parameters). This continues until the queue becomes empty. No further invocations of read2() occur until someone invokes read() again.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply making `read` a `synchronized` method?

You just call `read` directly instead of putting a workload ("call `read`") in a synchronized queue.  Your threads might have to wait a bit to get the synchronization lock, but as you said `read` executes very quickly, so it should not be a problem.

(I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem yet, but here is what I think I understand: all `read` does is start method `read2` on a new thread.  However it seems that there is some thread-safety issue with `read` since you do not want (for unexplained reasons) many `read` to execute in parallel.)

**EDIT**: I realized I don't know if `read` is a method of a single shared object, a static method or if it is present in many objects.  If it is the latter, just making the method `synchronized` wouldn't do much good; you would need to get some global lock (maybe a lock on the **class** that contains `read`) either before calling `read`, or within `read`.

Comment: read() is a method present in many objects. Synchronizing read() without a queue is not enough because only one read2() operation may be active at a time. Meaning, you have to wait for the operation to complete (return the bytes read) before invoking read2() again.

Comment: OK, I did not understand that part.  Then maybe you should not call `read` at all but call directly `read2`, with some global lock.  You might have many threads waiting on the lock, which I don't think would be a problem even with 1000 threads.